# Xcode didn't launch the right application

Tags: flutter, xcode, ios17, xcode15

I've upgraded my system to use Xcode 15 and iOS 17. Since this upgrade i discover a weird behavior on one of my project and not the others.

```bash
flutter run -t lib/entrypoints/generations/main.dart --flavor generations
```

As you can see on the following image, I've run my app using the 'generations' flavor and the 'generations' bundle id but Xcode tried to launch one of my other flavor named "zim" which have the bundle id egdigital.zimradio.Zim-Radio.

In fact xcode tried to run the flavor defined inside the "default value for command line build" instead of current flavor.

If I run my app on a device with a lower iOS version, I didn't have the issue.
I can also reproduce that on emulator and the issue is little different : On a fresh new emulator, Xcode will deploy the previous flavor that I used. Smell like weird cache issue.

This problem is weird and I need some help !

Flutter 3.13.8
Xcode: 15.0.1
MacOS: 14.2.3
IPhone SE 2gen: iOS 17.1.2

[image]

On my device, i've didn't have any visible certificate to accept inside General -> VPN & Device Management.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
Domain: IDELaunchCoreDevice
Code: 0
Recovery Suggestion: Verify that the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. Open Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
Domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain
Code: -10814
User Info: {
    "_LSFunction" = runEvaluator;
    "_LSLine" = 1608;
}
```

EDIT :

After running `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode` the issue persist but error is little different. I take for this new take an other flavor 'named' ODS on the same project.

XCode didn't try to find previous app (because I deleted all possible caches) but it still fail to open the new one created.

Error :
[image]

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
Domain: IDELaunchCoreDevice
Code: 0
Recovery Suggestion: Verify that the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. Open Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
Domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain
Code: -10814
User Info: {
    "_LSFunction" = runEvaluator;
    "_LSLine" = 1608;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,8";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.1.2 (21B101)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.40.14";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 4624;
    "operation_errorCode" = 0;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDELaunchCoreDevice;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--
```

No certificate to accept :
[image]

App is here, didn't understand why Xcode fail...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think found the solution :

My xscheme files (one per flavor) used as 'buildConfiguration' the default value like 'Debug' or 'Release' instead of the flavor based one : 'Debug-generations' or 'Debug-ods'.

Because of that, xcode used the defaultBuildConfiguration and launched my first in list flavor (zim).

Strangely, first build on fresh simulator fail but the following are working perfectly.
Anyways, not big issue i can work peacefully now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using --dart-define=app.flavor=generations, I was facing the same issue and it got resolved using this,

Try either of these commands

1. flutter run -t lib/entrypoints/generations/main.dart --flavor generations --dart-define=app.flavor=generations
2. flutter run -t lib/entrypoints/generations/main.dart --dart-define=app.flavor=generations

//Update

app.flavor is an enviroment variable which I accept to set my flavor and then the above code works

```
    const String appFlavor =String.fromEnvironment('app.flavor');
```

Use this appFlavor to set my app flavor and then the 2 flutter run solutions work. Do let me know if its working or not.

Comment: Also if you want to run it without using command you can add --dart-define=app.flavor=generations in your additional run args and add your flavor inside Build flavor of your run configuration. Do let me know if you are still facing any issue. @Eng

Comment: I will take a look :o ! (Do you know what xcode / flutter use this dart-define 'app.flavor' ?

Comment: Ideally --flavor should set the flavor but as it doesn't dart-define app.flavor does it for us. dart-define is used to set the env variables during a build or a run. If this doesn't work I will confirm on my end if I made any other changes related to app.flavor

Comment: Okay just checked I am taking the flavor from environment variable and then passing it using --dart-define=app.flavor. I will update my answer

Comment: const String appFlavor =String.fromEnvironment('app.flavor');

Why i need to use this string and how ? How that will fix my xcode issue ?

Comment: Your solution didn't work. Also i didn't know how it could have worked. How a dart define can fix xcode wrong app selection on iPhone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256204/discussion-between-eng-and-vikas).